# tkinter update label with filename from menu class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, menu

I am trying to follow an object-oriented approach to create a simple tkinter app to display some data but I am struggling to pass values between the MenuBar class in which a file is selected and the main App class where ultimately I will work with the file. For now I am just trying to display the filename on screen in a Label. I have tried to pass the filename as a tk.StringVar but this is not being updated on screen. Simplified code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd #needed for file dialogues
from tkinter import ttk

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.file_audio = tk.StringVar()

    fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Select file...", command=self.select_file)
    self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

  # method to select a single file
  def select_file(self):
    self.file_audio = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file')
    
class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title('Title')
    self.geometry("800x300")
    
    self.menubar = MenuBar()
    self.config(menu=self.menubar)

    self.createWidgets()

  def createWidgets(self):
    self.file_info = ttk.Label(self, text = self.menubar.file_audio)
    self.file_info.grid(column=1, row=1)

def main():
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: _"For now I am just trying to print the filename on screen."_ - your code doesn't show that. Where are you trying to print it?

Comment: I thought the ttk.Label() call in createWidgets() would do this, taking the value of file_audio and printing this. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "print" usually means a particular thing - calling the `print` function.

Comment: OK, question now edited to say display rather than print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `textvariable` option should be used instead of `text` option in `ttk.Label(...)`

```py
  def createWidgets(self):
    self.file_info = ttk.Label(self, textvariable = self.menubar.file_audio)
    self.file_info.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

2. Use `self.file_audio.set(...)` instead of assignment inside `MenuBar.select_file()`

```py
  def select_file(self):
    self.file_audio.set(fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file'))
```

Comment: Thank you @acw1668, that works as required. I see why I should use .set() instead of assignment, but why do I not also use .get() method to put the value of self.file_audio into the label?

Comment: Using `textvariable` option can automatically update the text of the label when the variable is updated.  You can use `.get()` on `text` option, but you need to do it manually whenever the variable is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But I have added a line of code that I think might be useful. In the "createWidgets" method, you should call self.menubar.select_file().

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd #needed for file dialogues
from tkinter import ttk

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.file_audio = tk.StringVar()

    fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Select file...", command=self.select_file)
    self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

  # method to select a single file
  def select_file(self):
    self.file_audio = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file')

class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title('Title')
    self.geometry("800x300")
 
    self.menubar = MenuBar()
    self.config(menu=self.menubar)

    self.createWidgets()

  def createWidgets(self):
    self.menubar.select_file() #Added line of code
    self.file_info = ttk.Label(self, text = self.menubar.file_audio)
    self.file_info.grid(column=1, row=1)

def main():
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this does not behave as intended. This opens the file dialogue as soon as the app loads, rather than on clicking Open a file... in the File menu